Can't add ios distribution certificate
I can't seem to add a distribution certificate in Visual Studio working with .net maui. I checked in the app store connection and my account shows I'm the Account Holder and admin and can do everything.
When I go to add my distribution certificate, it shows like this:

Things I tried:
I removed all certificates not active or in use on my developer account.
I removed all profiles in use.
I double-checked App Store Connect I have the right permissions.
I revoked the app store connect key and restored a new one.
One thing I see that is weird is that my account role shows I'm an Account Holder and not an Administrator or Admin like I see on other examples. what it looks like:

What's weird is that I have published a version of my app previously with the app store connect user. But for some reason, my profile vanished and I had to resign. So I know I have used this previously with the same account.
Any help would be appreciated thanks!

Have you tried removing the Apple Developer Account in VS, then re-creating a new API in the app connect store? setting the permission to admin and adding it in VS Apple Accounts.

I tested several times. the Role in VS Apple Account always shows the permission that was set when creating the App Store Connect API, and I can create the Distribution certificate normally.
As the workaround, you can try creating the distribution certificate from Apple Developer (it needs the CSR from Mac), or importing distribution certificate from other devices.

Hello. I have the same problem. Even when tem role is Administrator, iOS ditribution option appears greyed out. I cpuld create the distribution certificate using XCode in Mac. That way, the certificate is listed in VS2022 certificates dialogs, but the status column says that t is not in the key chain. How can I add it?

Certificate in Apple Developer site can only be downloaded as .cer file, not .p12 as VS expects to be.
